# Inserting into Dynamic table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Currently I have a database that has a 'Log' table. It has over 200 million rows in production. I want to break this table into product types, ProdALog, ProdBLog, ProdCLog, etc. I want to be able to allow the creation of a new table without having to update my edmx and redeploy my service application.

Logs are pushed to a service, that service then inserts into the Log table

```
context.Logs.Add(log);
//insert 100
context.SaveChanges()
// rebuild context and loop till all logs are inserted
```

I want my service to be able to basically do

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (Source, Message) VALUES ('HERE', 'Something Happened')"), table)
```

Do I lose anything by making the call this way in terms of performance? Is this a good approach to the issue that 'Selects take to long' (by splitting the table, a product would only look for logs in his associated table. So a product with minimal logs wont be bogged down by logs from other products.)

I can update the edmx for each new table created and then have a switch

```
switch(type) {
  case "ProdA": context.ProdALogs.Add(new ProdALog(...)); break;
  case "ProdB": context.ProdBLogs.Add(new ProdBLog(...)); break;
  case "ProdC": context.ProdCLogs.Add(new ProdCLog(...)); break;
  default: context.Logs.Add(new Log(...)); break;
}
```

But this requires republishing the service each time a new table is created/removed

I was hoping to have a cleaner way to do something like this via Entity Framework 6.

**Additional Info**

Log table is (Id, ProdId, Type, Source, Message, Dat, Tim, Level)
I have indexes for (ProdId, Dat, Tim, Level), (ProdId, Dat, Level), (ProdId)
Indexes are rebuilt each night.
Dat is an int = 20160708
Tim is an int = 81552 //(8:15:52) || 225000 (22:50:00)

I understand that this does not reduce the number of logs, but it does 'limit' the logs that get processed on each read.

Logs are being read by Entity Framework 6 from a web page which requests no more than 10,000 logs. Searches are timing out because they are taking longer than 60 seconds.

Comment: Why not add (or keep it if its already this way) a new column to the existing table called `ProductType` (or something like that)? With the correct indexes in place performance should not be an issue. 200 million log records is not that much (unless you are storing binary or extremely long texts) and by splitting it up the overall number of records will not decrease? What is the real issue, what are you experiencing that makes you want to do this to begin with?

Comment: *Based on your edit* -> Then you need to capture the query(ies) that is generated and profile them. With the correct index(es) you should be able to reduce that time significantly. If you want help doing that I suggest you update the question with the database service you are using (sql server, oracle, etc) and the generated quer(ies) that need to be tuned.

Comment: I would like to know if you found a solution and also if you have the ef core implementation to excess tables/ extract data